# List View Web Part Selector

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part

I have 3 connected web parts on my SharePoint page. Web Part 1 is a list view web part that connects to web part 2 another list view web part. These are 2 separate lists joined via ID. My 3rd web part is an InfoPath form web part.

When I select an item in web part 1, web part 2 does filter and show me the correct corresponding record. But the record in the 2nd web part needs to then be selected to display the correct info path form in the 3rd web part.

Is there anyway to make the item returned by web part 2 selected by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. 
I edited web part 1, under Miscellaneous I unchecked "Send first row to connected Web Parts when page loads".

Now when the page loads Web Part 1 displays all my records. Web Parts 2 and 3 do not display any records which is fine.

When I select a record in web part 1, web part 2 displays the correct corresponding record already selected which then populates web part 3 with the correct InfoPath form.